# ScrollView With AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a weird output with autoLayout used for following scenario.

I have 4 sub pages to scroll. (subPage or scrollPage has been designed separately with autoLayout).

MainView has a scrollView component which loads the sub pages.

Everything is fine except the starting. After first load, the sub page components are not arranged properly. As soon as it receives a first tap/touch, automatically re-scrolls/re-arranges to proper places. which looks like a bug.

The loading creates problem. I have attached 2 images for reference for the above scenarios.
FirstOne at the first loading [image]

Second one just after tapping on scroll area [image]

Second one is the proper one. I need to show this instead of the first.
Need help to fix this.

Thanks,
Satyaranjan

One more thing to note,
[myScroll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320*pageNumber, 0, 320 , 240) animated:NO];
this is not working As I am using dynamic width for the subPage. Because it will vary for iPhon5 and iPhone6

Comment: Is there any output in the console when you load the scrollPage such as AutoLayout warnings? When and where are you adding the constraints? Can you post the some code that you are using to construct the view?

Comment: [scrollLayer setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*noofpages, scrollLayer.frame.size.height)];
CGRect sFrame=[scrollLayer bounds];sFrame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
for (int i=0;i<noofpages;i++){sFrame.origin.x=i*sFrame.size.width;
PageController *tpc=[[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Page"];
[[tpc view] setFrame:scrollFrame];[self addChildViewController:tpc];[scrollLayer addSubview:[tpc view]];}
scrollFrame.origin.x=savedPageId*scrollFrame.size.width;
[scrollLayer scrollRectToVisible:scrollFrame animated:NO];

Comment: warning msg : <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faa62f7b080 UIScrollView:0x7faa62f781e0.leading == UIView:0x7faa62f7a810.leadingMargin - 16>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faa62f7b0d0 UIView:0x7faa62f7a810.trailingMargin == UIScrollView:0x7faa62f781e0.trailing - 16>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faa62f7b120 UIView:0x7faa62f7a810.centerX == UIScrollView:0x7faa62f781e0.centerX>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you generally don't want to set the scrollView's contentSize when using autolayout -- if your sub views are laid out correctly, it will do that automatically.

Try this:

- constrain all four of scrollView's edges to its parent
- make sure translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is NO for all views
- Create a view called "contentView" and parent it to the scrollView.
- pin all four of contentViews's edges to scrollView
- parent your subviews to contentView and arrange them with autolayout

If for some reason you need to change the size of a subview programmaticly, you need to override its intrinsicContentSize method to return the correct size after the change. After the change, you might need to call the view's sizeToFit method from its parent view (not sure about that -- it may happen automatically).

In general, when using autolayout, you should almost never explicitly set the size of anything. If it can't be avoided, you should do it by creating height/width constraints and modifying them at runtime in the updateConstraints method.

EDIT:

I made an example project which demonstrates how to set up a scrollView and a couple other things.

Take a look!

https://github.com/annabd351/AutolayoutTemplate

Comment: Without setting the content size, the first subpage will display and it will not scroll. Abt your steps to fix, can you please elaborate more or send me a link how to constrain edges. I am using the "add missing" constraints option.

Comment: Here are a few links: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/

Comment: I made you a sample project. :-p  It's 100% autolayout -- no code at all.  It has several views (some auto-sizing) inside a scrollView.  You *definitely* don't need to set contentSize if you have it set up correctly. You can use the storyboard in the project as a template -- just add your custom classes and hook them up!

Comment: Thanks for the sample. But it didn't help me. It contains default/static data/pages. My situation is to create dynamic no.of pages.

Comment: It's just a template -- delete the static views and add your own. If you do it programmatically, add the views to the scroll view's content view, and then call setNeedsLayout in the content view.

Comment: Thanks @Anna, for all the help. The issue has been fixed with "Use Auto Layout" and "Use Size Class". mixing both creating some issues.